# How to remove plug in styles for WPForms Lite

Tags: plugins, wp-enqueue-style

I would like to remove the preset style sheets that WPForms Lite applies to its forms. So that I can use my own and not have to cause excess bloat by overriding the preset stylesheet.

Currently, I have my own enqueuer which works for everything else eg loading and removing styles and scripts as I please, but for WPForms, I have hit a brick wall. I could have the wrong reference for the styles, but inspecting the plugin code all I came up with was `wpforms-full` and `wpforms-base`.

Focusing just on the relevant part, my code in functions.php currently goes like this:

```
function my_enqueuer() {
    wp_deregister_style( 'wpforms-full' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'wpforms-base' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueuer' );
```

But the style sheets for the form still loads. Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: If those are the correct handles and the correct action, try playing with the action priority. Something like this `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueuer', 9999);`

Comment: Increasing the priority doesn't appear to do the trick, which  I guess suggests that the handles are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so this is a little embarrassing.
I noticed whilst looking for the handle this little snippet in the plugin code

```
if ( wpforms_setting( 'disable-css', '1' ) == '1' ) {
```

As it turns out, this refers to a setting you can utilise. You can simply do this through the plugin settings.
In your dashboard go to WPForms > Settings and under the General heading select 'No Styling', and hey presto, job done.

[image]

Sometimes things are a little easier than you assume.

Comment: Thanks! I figured if a setting liked this existed it would be a setting specific to each form, so I didn't even think to check the global settings.